# Mastercard purchase protection benefits for stolen items

Tags: credit-card, mastercard

I have a Visa signature card that covers any purchase within 90 days of purchasing date from theft or damage, the cost of the item will be refunded.

Apparently Mastercard offers a similar benefit but I can't find if all World Mastercard cards include this benefit or not. I know Platinum Mastercard does not include this benefit. Does it depend from the issuing financial institution or from whether the card is World or World Elite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent MasterCard benefit is called "purchase assistance" and is described on [this page](https://www.mastercard.us/en-us/consumers/features-benefits/card-benefits.html):

> Purchase assurance
>
> Provides coverage for most items you purchase with your eligible MasterCard if the item is damaged or stolen within 90 days of the date of purchase.

However, with any of these credit card benefits, individual card issuing institutions can opt-in or opt-out of any individual benefits. You need to ask the card issuer that you are interested in if the card you are looking at offers this purchase assistance benefit.

Comment: And it's easy to document 'damaged'. My wife cracked her iPhone screen a few months after purchase. Sent in the receipt from Apple for repair and we were reimbursed. Tell them your iPad was stolen, I'd imagine some proof would be needed.

Comment: When I had some recently purchased stuff stolen out of my car, they required a police report in order to process the claim.